# Measuring force of a punch on iphone

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, measure

I'm creating a simple app that measures the force exerted by the user from punching in the air while holding the device. The only way I know is to use the built-in accelerometer. Now  i was able to get the acceleration values using the UIAccelerometerDelegate protocol

```
 - (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration.
```

The problem is, I dont know what to do with these  values, for now I get the sum of x,y, and z. Is there any formula or whatsoever I could use so I could provide users a more accurate result?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a physics question more than a programming question.  First, you need to get the magnitude of the acceleration from the vector the API returns:

> a = square root(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)

Then, you can use Newton's formula to get the force.

> F=ma

Since you have the acceleration, all you need to do is multiply by the mass of the phone and you're done.  (Though you may want to convert the result to a particular unit of measure.)

Mind you, pressure would probably be a more meaningful value than force.  For instance, I might want the phone to describe the strength of my punch in pounds per square inch.  But you can't get that without knowing the surface area of the user's fist.

Comment: Thanks Peter! though i already have the acceleration values, i'm not sure if what i'm getting is the actual values upon punching of the user.What i did was i set a condition if value is greater than kNumber(in my case 1), if the condition is met, that's the only time i record the value. In short, the result is always the first value that is greater than 1.

Comment: I've tried using timer, user must punch with all his might for a certain period of time let's say 5 seconds.. then after that n number of seconds, the highest value reached will be recorded. I think it is more accurate this way but what I want is to record the force right away once it detects a punch motion. Is there a better way to do this?